# Problema al iterar un array con arrays y objetos

Tags: javascript, array, api

Les comento el siguiente problema:

Estoy trabajando con una API de personajes de una serie y estos están organizados de la siguiente manera: Son 34 paginas con 20 personajes cada una. Lo que hice por ahora es un bucle 'for' que me recorra la API 34 veces y me lleve todos los resultados a un array usando push (no se si esto esta bien pero fue la vuelta que le encontre).

Como cada uno de estos personajes tiene un id, un estado (vivo, muerto o desconocido), nombre, etc. estoy buscando una forma de poder filtrarlos y que solo muestre los que cumplan ciertos requisitos.

Por ejemplo poder aplicar los filtros "vivo" "episodio 1" y que llame todos los que cumplan estos requisitos.

Perdon si es mucho, pero recien estoy empezando con esto de las API y se me complica un poco el tema de filtrarlos y ordenarlos.

Desde ya, gracias.

(Por si alguno le interesa o ya la conoce es la API de rick and morty: https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation)

Edito y agrego el codigo que estoy usando:

```
function llenarTodos(){
    for (i = 1; i< 34 ; i++){
        const API_URL = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${i}`
        fetch(API_URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => 
            todos.push(data.results))
    }
}
```

Con ese codigo estoy tratando de llevar a todos los personajes a un array y despues poder filtrar desde ahi

Comment: La API tienes una opcion `filter` donde puedes filtrar lo que necesites.  Deberias agregar tu codigo para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta para poder agregar el codigo de la funcion que uso para llamar a todos los personajes

Comment: Si quieres tener los datos de forma local es correcto recorrer toda la API, pero no es lo ideal, ¿qué pasaría si en un futuro son 35 o 36 páginas en lugar de solo 34? Según la documentación, con este endpoint `/api/character?status=alive` obtendrías los personajes vivos, sin embargo no es posible filtrarlos por número de episodio a través de `/characters` por lo que una posible solución sería filtrar por episodio `/api/episode/1` y luego consultar cada uno de los personajes que devuelve esa consulta para verificar su estatus.

Comment: Ya volví a ver la información que devuelve el endpoint `/api/character` y para cada personaje devuelve también un array con los episodios de ocurencia. Para evitar la llamada a `/api/episode`, otra posible solución sería procesar la información de ese array para saber en que episodio salió, de este modo solo haces una única llamada a `/api/character` y de paso filtras directamente por `status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion .filter, que es especificamente para eso, te devuelve el array filtrado, por ejemplo el siguiente codigo retornaria todos los personajes vivos en el array 'vivos':

```
const vivos = todos.filter((personaje) => {
        return personaje.status === 'Alive' 
    })
```

Basado en este ejemplo puedes expandir la funcionalidad a tus necesidades. En la funcion filter lo que esta en el return es el criterio de filtrado si quieres agregar mas condicionales a este puedes hacer cosas como por ejemplo ver si esta vivo y si su primer episodio en el que salio fue el 6:

```
return personaje.status=== "Alive" && personaje.episode[0] === 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/6'
```

Con estos ejemplos te puedes basar e implementar los filtros necesarios.

Aqui esta la documentacion de filter, para que le eches un ojo.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Esto es una respuesta parcial puesto que solo "funcionaría" para filtrar a los personajes vivos. Lo coloco entre comillas porque en filtro correcto sería usar `personaje.status === 'Alive'`. La pregunta abarca también el porder filtrar por número de episodio, cosa que implicaría un poco más de trabajo.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario,edite mi respuesta en base a este.

Comment: Gracias, lo pude resolver con este metodo